# Laravel 5.3 Post search with session for complex search

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i have a search routes like that

```
Route::post('search', 'SearchController@index');
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@index');
```

now i'm searching the result from home page form etc 6 form fields then it redirect me on the search page with result but when i click it second time on pagination page it does not work for me.i'm using session in it for remember data that i post for the home. i can search also on this page if i have session then i read second condition in my case.

Controller is below

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

    if( Request::get('select_menu') !='' ){

                $conditions = array();
                $conditions['city'] = Request::get('city');
                $conditions['area'] = Request::get('area');
                $conditions['purpose'] = Request::get('status');
                $results = Property::where($conditions)->whereBetween('price', array(1000, 10000))->paginate(6);
                Session::set('formDataSession', $conditions);

            }
        elseif(Session::has('formDataSession')){

                $getSession = Session::get('formDataSession');

                $conditions = array();
                $conditions['city'] = $getSession['city'];
                $conditions['area'] = $getSession['area'];
                $conditions['purpose'] = $getSession['purpose'];
                $results = Property::where($conditions)->whereBetween('price', array(1000, 10000))->paginate(6);

            }
    return view('search', array('page' => 'search','results'=>$results));
}
```

Comment: Your `if` part doesn't make any sense. You're not setting `$formData` anywhere, or `$conditions` too.

Comment: Also, please clarify what exactly is not working? First set of results, or just the part where you take parameters from session?

Comment: when first time i post data from form it gives me results correct and go to index function on search controller and then i click second page it return nothing.

Comment: first condition only run first time on submit form from home page